# How to substring a text easily

Tags: c#, html, text, substring, partial

Alright here the question. This is an example text

```
Nokia 700<span>Stok Kodu: 389952</span>
<br><span style="background-image:none; margin:0; padding:0; font:14px/18px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">Nokia 700 Cep Telefonu PDA, Dokunmatik, Bluetooth, Radyo</span>
```

I want to get "Nokia 700" which starts with index 0 and ends with `<span>` and i am able to do it with the way below

```
var singleNode = myDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(srxProductName);
string srProductName = singleNode.InnerHtml.ToString()
    .Substring(0, singleNode.InnerHtml.ToString().IndexOf("<span>"));
```

The question is i wonder are there any easier or more practical way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the node containing your text in `singleNode`, you can just extract the first child node, which should be a text node, and get its value:

```
var productName = singleNode.ChildNodes[0].Value;
```